# Quartz.net Job unhandled exception behaviour

Tags: error-handling, thread-safety, quartz.net, jobs, unhandled-exception

I am implementing quartz.net scheduler to my project, and have some questions about the workings of this library:

1. What happens if one job raises an exception without a catch block (unhandled exception)? Would this cause the process to terminate and AppDomain Unloading? Would other jobs suffer?
2. Does Quartz.net lib try to restart jobs that raised unhandled exceptions? Or should I implement it manually in my project?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I can determine being a user of Quartz.net myself.

1. If your job (or quartz itself) raises an unhandled exception like all .net2 or later programs it will take our your app domain. You could try using AppDomain.UnhandledException handler.
2. I think by default RequestRecovery is true but you can set this to false when you schedule the job.

Comment: Also there are more details on how to ensure your job catches exceptions here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3246277/handle-jobexecutionexception-in-quartz-net

Comment: This is not true anymore with the current version of Quartz.NET - the exception (`VetoedException`) is caught, and the this a silent "complete job" and `return`... no more bubbeling to the AppDomain ...

Comment: Please see my blogpost @ http://andreas.niedermair.name/unhandeled-exception-in-quartz-net-job for more details on the implementation!